# What platform toolkit runs on what OS?

Tags: visual-studio

So after searching forever, I'm still not clear on exactly what platform toolkit runs on what OS.   I understand the `_xp` versions are needed to run on XP, but does that many anything that doesn't have `_xp` runs on `vista` or later?  What about with the new Visual 2022 (v143)?  It would be more clear if they just used vXXX_minos.

Thanks.